# Getting SVN to shadow commits to a CVS repository

Tags: svn, repository, cvs, shadowing

Is there a way to monitor commits to a CVS repository on a daily basis say, and for those changes to be replicated in a local SVN repository. Ideally maintaining commit comments.

A little perl ditty maybe?

Thanks, Steve.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [commitinfo](http://cvsman.com/cvs-1.12.12/cvs_189.php) to run a script each time changes are committed. The file you run can be a simple script, even Perl (if you like suffering), simply committing the changes to your SVN.